# Magento 2.2.5 : Add custom field in product attribute add form

Tags: magento2, magento-2.2.5, custom-field, ui-form

Go to : **Store -> Attributes -> Product -> Edit attribute**

I want to add custom dropdown as like **Used in Product Listing** dropdown.

I added it. But, It's display in **Properties** tab instead of **Storefront Properties** tab.

Please help me how to add that in **Properties** tab.

I upload my code and screenshot here.

> CompanyName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Edit\Tab\Front.php

```
<?php

namespace CompanyName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Edit\Tab;

class Front extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Edit\Tab\Front
{
    protected function _prepareForm()
    {

        parent::_prepareForm();
        $attributeObject = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('entity_attribute');
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create(
            ['data' => ['id' => 'edit_form', 'action' => $this->getData('action'), 'method' => 'post']]
        );

        $yesnoSource = $this->_yesNo->toOptionArray();
        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset(
            'front_fieldset',
            ['legend' => __('Storefront Properties'), 'collapsable' => $this->getRequest()->has('popup')]
        );
        $fieldset->addField(
            'used_in_custom',
            'select',
            [
                'name' => 'used_in_custom',
                'label' => __('Used in Custom'),
                'title' => __('Used in Custom'),
                'note' => __('Depends on design theme.'),
                'values' => $yesnoSource,
            ]
        );
        $this->setForm($form);
        return \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic::_prepareForm();
    }
}
```

> CompanyName/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_attribute_add_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
     <fieldset name="front_fieldset">
        <field name="used_in_custom" sortOrder="130" formElement="checkbox">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <notice translate="true">Depends on design theme.</notice>
                <dataType>boolean</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Used in Custom</label>
                <dataScope>used_in_custom</dataScope>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <checkbox>
                    <settings>
                        <valueMap>
                            <map name="false" xsi:type="number">0</map>
                            <map name="true" xsi:type="number">1</map>
                        </valueMap>
                        <prefer>toggle</prefer>
                    </settings>
                </checkbox>
            </formElements>
        </field>
     </fieldset>
</form>
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try via plugin method:

> CompanyName/ModuleName/etc/adminhtml/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Edit\Tab\Front">
        <plugin name="companyname_attribute_edit_form" type="CompanyName\ModuleName\Plugin\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Edit\Tab\Front" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> CompanyName/ModuleName/Plugin/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Attribute/Edit/Tab/Front.php

```
<?php
namespace CompanyName\ModuleName\Plugin\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Edit\Tab;

class Front
{

    /**
     * @var Yesno
     */
    protected $_yesNo;

    /**
     * @param Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno $yesNo
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno $yesNo
    ) {
        $this->_yesNo = $yesNo;
    }

    /**
     * Get form HTML
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function aroundGetFormHtml(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Edit\Tab\Front $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    )
    {

        $yesnoSource = $this->_yesNo->toOptionArray();
        $form = $subject->getForm();
        $fieldset = $form->getElement('front_fieldset');
        $fieldset->addField(
            'used_in_custom',
            'select',
            [
                'name' => 'used_in_custom',
                'label' => __('Used in Custom'),
                'title' => __('Used in Custom'),
                'note' => __('Depends on design theme.'),
                'values' => $yesnoSource,
            ]
        );
        return $proceed();
    }
}
```

After run command : php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: Thanks Man :) It's working. Can you please give me one more answer ? How to save that value on save action ? that use_in_custom column available in catalog_eav_attribute table.

Comment: let me check and know you

Comment: Okay sure.... :)

Comment: have you created custom field " use_in_custom" in catalog_eav_attribute table?

Comment: Yes... It's already created.

Comment: Then no need to add any more code for this. Pls try to save it is working fine my end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81811/discussion-between-emipro-technologies-pvt-ltd-and-abdul).

Comment: Hi @Abdul I have followed your post/answer everything working fine but we are facing an issue with displaying selected value after saving at admin end attribute level can you please suggest is there any thing i missed it.  .

Comment: Hi@Abdul. I also need some custiom fields for my attributes. Is it possible, that your share this extension?

Answer (score 0):

@abdul, Your code is working fine, but in my case the selected value does not loaded on form.

So after debug i found that we can get it from registry.

> class Front {
> /**
> * Get form HTML
> *
> * @return string
> */
>
> ```
> /**
> * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
> */
> private $registry;
>
> public function __construct(
>     \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
>     )
> {
>     $this->registry = $registry;
> }
>
>
> public function aroundGetFormHtml(
>     \Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Attribute\Edit\Tab\Front
>      $subject,
>     \Closure $proceed
> )
> {
>     $attributeObject = $this->registry->registry('entity_attribute');
>     $Desc = $attributeObject->getData('test_description');
>     
>     $form = $subject->getForm();
>
>     $fieldset = $form->getElement('front_fieldset');
>     $fieldset->addField(
>         'test_description',
>         'textarea',
>         [
>             'name' => 'test_description',
>             'label' => __('Wizard Description'),
>             'value' => $Desc
>         ],            
>     );
>     return $proceed();
> } }
> ```

I was using textare, For select you need to select from registry data.